# How to copy and paste columns from one matrix to another in Math.NET Numerics?

Tags: c#, matrix

Let's say I have the following Matrix-1

```
// Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(3,4,(i,j) => i*10*j).ToString()
Matrix-1 3x4-Double
0   0   0   0
0  10  20  30
0  20  40  60
```

**now, based on column indices values present in an array, I need to create a new matrix from the above matrix.**

For example, if the value of indices, corresponding to the columns that need to be copied is (`int[] indiciesToBeCopied = new int[]{0,3}`)  then, the resulting new **Matrix-2** would like like following:

```
Matrix-2 3x2-Double
0     0  
0    30  
0    60
```

How can I copy certain columns from one matrix to another?

Comment: Is there any reason not to just write a simple function with a loop that copies the columns value by value?

Comment: @JonasH: The reason is to avoid writing a function :)

Comment: Fair enough, but if your looking for existing functions, would it not be easier to check the documentation?

Comment: @JonasH: I did check the documentation at numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html but could not understand how can I copy the columns specified in an array.